# Trouble importing photos to windows

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, photos

Hi I am trying to import photos from samsung galaxy s2 using windows photo gallery. When I do this it imports all of my music album art and mixes it all together with my photos. 
When I simply try to copy with explorer however, it doesn't auto rotate my pictures. 
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [Picassa](http://picasa.google.com), for example, which only imports photos. I find it very convenient for importing, browsing and minor adjustments to photos.